# Remover chave antiga de known_hosts (Warning: Possible DNS Spoofing detected)

Tags: ssh

Ao acessar via linha de comando em Linux/MacOS, um erro parecido como o a seguir poderá aparecer

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@ WARNING: POSSIBLE DNS SPOOFING DETECTED! @ 
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
The RSA host key for dominio.com.br 
and the key for the corresponding IP address 123.123.123.123 
is unknown. This could either mean that 
DNS SPOOFING is happening or the IP address for the host 
and its host key have changed at the same time. 
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ 
@ WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED! 
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ 
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY! 
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)! 
(...)
```

UM erro parecido também acontece ao usar uma GUI, como o Nautilus no Ubuntu, de modo que não há como navegar por uma pasta de um servidor que teve uma alteração legítima.

**Como resolver isso**?

Answer (score 2):

Em seu terminal, digite o comando:

> **ssh-keygen -R *dominio.com.br***

Esse erro ocorre porque em algum momento no passado a máquina local acessou o servidor remoto e gravou em `~/.ssh/known_hosts file` uma *assinatura* de quem era o servidor remoto. Porém com essa mensagem, ele está alertando você que a máquina remota não tem mais a mesma assinatura.

**Nestes casos, antes de remover, procure saber porque houve esse erro**. Se sabe que a máquina remota realmente alterou, como a exemplo de ter recriado uma máquina virtual para hospedar o mesmo domínio, basta remover a assinatura anterior com o comando listado.

Saiba mais também sobre [Ataque man-in-the-middle](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ataque_man-in-the-middle)